# ThreadPoolExecutor - How can you bring results to Excel?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using the Yahoo finance API to extract data using `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Can anyone show me how to bring the output to excel if possible? Thanks

```
import yfinance as yf
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def get_stats(ticker):
    info = yf.Tickers(ticker).tickers[ticker].info
    print(f"{ticker} {info['currentPrice']} {info['marketCap']}")

ticker_list = ['AAPL', 'ORCL', 'PREM.L', 'UKOG.L', 'KOD.L', 'TOM.L', 'VELA.L', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'GOOG']

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(get_stats, ticker_list)
```

Output:

```
VELA.L 0.035 6004320
UKOG.L 0.1139 18496450
PREM.L 0.461 89516976
ORCL 76.755 204970377216
MSFT 294.8669 2210578825216
TOM.L 0.604 10558403
KOD.L 0.3 47496900
AMZN 3152.02 1603886514176
AAPL 171.425 2797553057792
GOOG 2698.05 1784584732672
```

Comment: What's the type of the output you shared ? Also, how should look like the table on a spreadsheet ?

Comment: The output is 3 columns of data.  Ticker, Price and Market Cap.  So, in the spreadsheet, I would like 3 columns.

Comment: _The output is 3 columns of data_, so you mean it's a dataframe or what ? Can you `print(type(x))` assuming that `x` is your output..

Comment: I'm not familiar with this Threadpoolexecutor.  The output is what I get when I run the code, I don't think it's a dataframe but not sure.  I'm also not sure how to provide what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can make a empty list and feed id with every returned result by the API, then construct a dataframe from it and finally use [`pandas.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) to make the Excel spreadsheet.

Try this :

```
import yfinance as yf
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd


list_of_futures= []

def get_stats(ticker):
    info = yf.Tickers(ticker).tickers[ticker].info
    s= f"{ticker} {info['currentPrice']} {info['marketCap']}"
    list_of_futures.append(s)

ticker_list = ['AAPL', 'ORCL', 'PREM.L', 'UKOG.L', 'KOD.L', 'TOM.L', 'VELA.L', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'GOOG']

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(get_stats, ticker_list)
    
(
    pd.DataFrame(list_of_futures)
        [0].str.split(expand=True)
        .rename(columns={0: "Ticker", 1: "Price", 2: "Market Cap"})
        .to_excel("yahoo_futures.xlsx", index=False)
)
```

##### # Output (dataframe)

```
   Ticker   Price     Market Cap
0  UKOG.L   0.064       14417024
1  VELA.L  0.0205        3331721
2    AMZN   93.41   952940888064
3    GOOG    97.6  1261313982464
4    ORCL   82.72   223027183616
5   KOD.L    0.28       47330360
6    AAPL  148.11  2356148699136
7    MSFT  247.49  1844906819584
8   TOM.L   0.455        9117245
9  PREM.L    0.57      127782592
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea why I get this error? pd.DataFrame(list_of_futures)
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined. Did you mean: 'id'?

Comment: Yes, you need to `import pandas as pd`. I updated my answer ;)